# Adding version in my Laravel App automatically

Tags: laravel, git, bitbucket, versioning

I want to add a version on my Laravel app automatically when some new code is pushed in any branch, preferably using the SemVer convention.

I have found packages such as https://github.com/antonioribeiro/version and though this does solve the issue of actually having a consistent versioning system, I cannot figure out a way to automate the process.

More specifically I would like the version to be bumped up whenever changes are pushed to the repo, and ideally this should have to be consistent across all branches.

Also I would like this solution to work across all developers in the team (so preferably no local config).

Currently I am using bitbucket for repo hosting and Laravel Forge for development.

I am thinking that Bitbucket Pipelines would be of use, but I cannot think how this would work. The main problem I have is that if I use bitbucket to up the version and then commit and push this automatically then that would trigger another circle of upping the version and so on.

So ideally I would like the following workflow:

- Changes are commited
- (App version bump) //This can happen here
- New changes are pushed
- (App version bump) //Or here

I might be overthinking it so has anyone been in the same situation/has any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library you mentioned.
It provides a script for incrementing the semver version, which could be executed before each commit.

Install the dependency:

```
composer require pragmarx/version
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PragmaRX\Version\Package\ServiceProvider"
```

Go into the created `config/version.yml` and set the `mode` to `increment`.

For example you could create a script `.scripts/commit.sh` like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

php artisan version:patch
git add config/version.yml
git commit -m $1
```

When you are ready to commit, just add the files you want to push and call `./commit.sh "My commit message"` and you are up a patch version.

You could extend that script for further use (e.g. implement a parameter of what part of the version should be incremented [major,minor,patch]) or make use of [git-hooks](https://githooks.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, that is useful. However I don't see how this can work among many different developers -unless of course they all use the same script. In this case though that means that there is no ability to select specific changes to commit. Any further ideas maybe?

Comment: Hey @vasilaou, I updated my answer to be a bit more precise. If you need a quick solution, this should work just fine, even with multiple developers. 
If you need a more advanced version, you should look in to the `pre-commit` hook of https://githooks.com/.

Comment: Hi @Tobias, this is really helpful now! Thanks!